# Extract specific value from nested JSON

Tags: json, delphi

how to extract 'username' values from this JSON ?

```
{"sections": [{"layout_type": "two_by_two_right", "layout_content": {"two_by_two_item": {"channel": {"title": "", "channel_id": "0_17843667847017167_2207568091687618311", "channel_type": "hashtag_videos", "header": "", "context": "", "media": {"taken_at": 1577382674, "pk": 2207568091687618311, "id": "2207568091687618311_3271302467", "device_timestamp": 1577382645873821, "media_type": 2, "code": "B6i23uyhwcH", "client_cache_key": "MjIwNzU2ODA5MTY4NzYxODMxMQ==.2", "filter_type": 0, "image_versions2": {"candidates": [{"width": 640, "height": 640, "url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/75538180_158891128790372_2915252228956208913_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=1\u0026_nc_ohc=hH1jCS_K4_0AX9C0T7i\u0026oh=4674fefc753d5bd0b8d73a1eae713ff9\u0026oe=5EB25F94\u0026ig_cache_key=MjIwNzU2ODA5MTY4NzYxODMxMQ%3D%3D.2"}, {"width": 480, "height": 480, "url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/75538180_158891128790372_2915252228956208913_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=1\u0026_nc_ohc=hH1jCS_K4_0AX9C0T7i\u0026oh=d7d7c0dc6a85a7f84279f82f01ae648f\u0026oe=5E8F2B7C\u0026ig_cache_key=MjIwNzU2ODA5MTY4NzYxODMxMQ%3D%3D.2"}]}, "original_width": 640, "original_height": 640, "video_versions": [{"type": 101, "width": 480, "height": 480, "url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/81284582_860132527738160_2044993517273985872_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=108\u0026_nc_ohc=prTN_4HS4ggAX-jMljp\u0026oe=5E08C64F\u0026oh=1f4f2ea83708e3cb237c734a13d77eb2", "id": "17869777126539044"}, {"type": 102, "width": 480, "height": 480, "url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/81284582_860132527738160_2044993517273985872_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=108\u0026_nc_ohc=prTN_4HS4ggAX-jMljp\u0026oe=5E08C64F\u0026oh=1f4f2ea83708e3cb237c734a13d77eb2", "id": "17869777126539044"}, {"type": 103, "width": 480, "height": 480, "url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.2886-16/81284582_860132527738160_2044993517273985872_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_cat=108\u0026_nc_ohc=prTN_4HS4ggAX-jMljp\u0026oe=5E08C64F\u0026oh=1f4f2ea83708e3cb237c734a13d77eb2", "id": "17869777126539044"}], "has_audio": true, "video_duration": 59.0, "view_count": 232325.0, "location": {"pk": 1548113472095913, "name": "Al Madina Restaurant \u0130stanbul \u0645\u0637\u0639\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0627\u0633\u0637\u0646\u0628\u0648\u0644", "address": "Katip Mustafa \u00c7elebi Mahallesi, \u0130stiklal Caddesi, No: 39, Beyo\u011flu", "city": "Taksim, Istanbul, Turkey", "short_name": "Al Madina Restaurant \u0130stanbul \u0645\u0637\u0639\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0627\u0633\u0637\u0646\u0628\u0648\u0644", "lng": 28.98347, "lat": 41.03591, "external_source": "facebook_places", "facebook_places_id": 1548113472095913}, "lat": 41.03591, "lng": 28.98347, "user": {"pk": 3271302467, "username": "almadinarestaurant", "full_name": "\u0645\u0637\u0639\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0627\u0633\u0637\u0646\u0628\u0648\u0644", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/39932201_486538485090431_6123883117892599808_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_ohc=wxoDrVKISKgAX_WWM4y\u0026oh=4a1673082b00303466847defe8f92b4e\u0026oe=5E9DA725", "profile_pic_id": "1852849531101432950_3271302467", "friendship_status": {"following": false, "outgoing_request": false, "is_bestie": false, "is_restricted": false}, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "is_unpublished": false, "is_favorite": false, "can_see_primary_country_in_settings": false}, "can_viewer_reshare": true, "caption_is_edited": false, "comment_likes_enabled": false, "comment_threading_enabled": true, "has_more_comments": true, "next_max_id": 17876626159502158, "max_num_visible_preview_comments": 2, "preview_comments": [{"pk": 17915888494374591, "user_id": 6987374060, "text": "\u0647\u0627\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u062c\u0627\u062c\u0647 \u0645\u0627\u0631\u0627\u064a\u062f\u0647 \u0639\u0645\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0643\u0627\u0639\u062f \u062a\u0641\u062a\u0631 \u064a\u0645 \u0628\u0648\u0631\u0627\u0643", "type": 0, "created_at": 1577488612, "created_at_utc": 1577488612, "content_type": "comment", "status": "Active", "bit_flags": 0, "user": {"pk": 6987374060, "username": "noor_96raad", "full_name": "Noor Raad", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26344158_141357603211756_640350538315071488_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_ohc=LFE2-wR4dagAX-XDuYU\u0026oh=0c72339e4a0c3b477e8fdf6449f4b915\u0026oe=5E98A360", "profile_pic_id": "1700100273510087891_6987374060", "is_verified": false}, "did_report_as_spam": false, "share_enabled": false, "media_id": 2207568091687618311, "has_translation": true}, {"pk": 17876626159502158, "user_id": 4515669677, "text": "\u0628\u062d\u0633 \u0627\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0647\u0628\u0644 \u0648\u0627\u0646\u062a \u0628\u0627\u0635\u0635 \u0644\u0644\u0643\u0627\u0645\u064a\u0631\u0627 \u0643\u062f\u0627", "type": 0, "created_at": 1577492896, "created_at_utc": 1577492896, "content_type": "comment", "status": "Active", "bit_flags": 0, "user": {"pk": 4515669677, "username": "mohamedfarag855", "full_name": "Mohamed Farag", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/70126530_451622709033023_6583949114013122560_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_ohc=KvmYxtrSPO0AX-o0UK3\u0026oh=55a4efe0cc24bc6b9dc65dcc8e415334\u0026oe=5EA65D34", "profile_pic_id": "2148614249788813430_4515669677", "is_verified": false}, "did_report_as_spam": false, "share_enabled": false, "media_id": 2207568091687618311, "has_translation": true}], "can_view_more_preview_comments": true, "comment_count": 325, "like_count": 27989, "has_liked": false, "top_likers": [], "photo_of_you": false, "usertags": {"in": [{"user": {"pk": 303947497, "username": "cznburak", "full_name": "Burak \u00d6zdemir", "is_private": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/74400352_1433463380151317_5481021398098903040_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmct3-1.fna.fbcdn.net\u0026_nc_ohc=Op6_GQTK-XoAX9oe3dj\u0026oh=1227b143d2a639a4bf0266be36b5ae1f\u0026oe=5E9B58E0", "profile_pic_id": "2180993975116909614_303947497", "is_verified": true}, "position": [0.0, 0.0],
```

what i have tried so far :

```pascal
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  u : string;
  Item, Item2: IMember;
...
  json := TSuperObject.Create(list.Text);
  for item in json['sections'].AsArray do
  begin
    for item2 in item.AsObject['fill_items'].AsArray do
    begin
      u := item2.AsObject['username'].ToString;
    end;
  end;
```

I get an AV. What is the correct way to do it? i'm using XSuperJSON latest version.

**UPDATE**

The JSON was too long, so I paste it in this pastebin [JSON](https://pastebin.com/faeAzyha)

Comment: You did not indicate which line of code is raising the AV. But there is no `'fill_items'` element in the JSON you showed.

Comment: sorry about that, the JSON was too long, this is the full one `https://pastebin.com/faeAzyha` @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not going deep enough into the JSON hierarchy to reach the `'fill_items'` array and `'username'` string.

Inside the `'sections'` array, none of the objects in the array have a `'fill_items'` child array, so in your outer loop, `item.AsObject['fill_items']` does not return a valid element. The objects instead have a `'layout_content'` child object, and then inside that object is either a `'fill_items'` array or a `medias` array.

In the `'fill_items'` and `medias` arrays, each object in the array has a `'media'` child object, which has a `user` child object, which has the `'username'` child string.

With that said, try something more like this:

```pascal
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  u : string;
  Item, Item2: IMember;
  LC: ISuperObject;
  Arr: ISuperExpression;
...
  json := TSuperObject.Create(list.Text);
  for item in json['sections'].AsArray do
  begin
    LC := item.AsObject['layout_content'].AsObject;
    Arr := LC['fill_items'];
    if Arr.DataType = dtNil then
      Arr := LC['medias'];
    for item2 in Arr.AsArray do
    begin
      u := item2.AsObject['media'].AsObject['user'].AsObject['username'].ToString;
    end;
  end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
var
  json : ISuperObject;
  u : string;
  Item, Item2: IMember;
  LC: ISuperObject;
  Arr: ISuperExpression;
...
  json := SO(list.Text);
  for item in json.A['sections'] do
  begin
    LC := item.AsObject.O['layout_content'];
    if LC.Contain('fill_items') then
      Arr := LC.A['fill_items']
    else
      Arr := LC.A['medias'];
    for item2 in Arr do
    begin
      u := item.AsObject.O['media'].O['user'].S['username'];
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you, i got only the first 2 usernames then AV 8 times.

Comment: @Androidcode only the first 2 objects in the `sections` array have a `fill_items` array in their `layout_content` object, the other objects have a `medias` array instead. You will have to code for that. I have updated my answer. If you still get errors after this, you need to debug your code and figure it out for yourself, actually look at the JSON to see when it deviates from what you are expecting and then code for it accordingly.

Comment: ThankYou. M'Lord